# Detecting Outliers Of A Feature Relating to A Second

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, outliers

I have a measurement, let's say number of forest fires in each state, and populations of those states. How can I create a statistical test that would detect outlier fires in each state that are disproportionate to the population of that state? For example if Montana has 1/1000th of US population but has 1/10th of fires, this measure should detect that. What approaches can be used here?

Comment: You could do something like fires per capita. Outlier detection, however, is fraught with problems. What do you want to do when you identify "outlier" points?

Comment: Just report them basically, that's all. Fires per Capita.. I see.. That would be a good measure.. I cld  than look if each states fire per capita is too far away from average, by how many sigmas etc..

Comment: The trouble with seeing how many standard deviations above the mean a given observation is is that standard deviation and mean can be influenced by outliers.

Comment: Right. It would be great if I could create statistics for each dataset seperately (fires, population) then compare their respective statistics later.. Cant I say the null, H0, is that a state, both in fires count, and population count, is in the same bin, and try to reject that?

Comment: Now you're bringing in hypothesis testing. This makes me think that you're asking an XY problem where you think of solution Y to problem X, so you ask about Y instead of X. Do you have some X you want to solve?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by X,Y :)

Comment: "Y" is wanting to detect outliers or do some kind of hypothesis testing. "X" is the problem you really want to solve, for which you think "Y" is a viable solution.

Comment: Why fires per capita rather than fires per square mile? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

One way to compute this could be utilizing proportion z-tests. This test compares two [independent population proportions](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introstats1/chapter/comparing-two-independent-population-proportions/), I could, per state basis, calculate state pop vs total pop and fires in that states / all fires and run the z-test on those proportions, then check for significance.

In Python statsmodels there is a simple [library call](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest.html) to compute this,

```py
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest
count = np.array([5, 12])
nobs = np.array([83, 99])
stat, pval = proportions_ztest(count, nobs)
print('{0:0.3f}'.format(pval))
```

In the example, the pvalue from the call is >0.05 which means H0, two
proportions being same, is not rejected.